# Entity Framework 6 - Navigation Properties PK and FK are different types

Tags: entity-framework, mapping

I have an existing database that has a PK that is a numberic(18,0) and a FK that is an int.  When I try to use the navigation property EF throws an invalid cast exception.

Is there a way to map this relationship that will sort out the invalid cast?

In the code below promo_cfg.pc_id is numeric(18,0) and promo.pc_id is int.

```
public class PromotionMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Promotion>
{
    public PromotionMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(p => p.PromotionId);

        // Properties

        // table and column mappings
        this.ToTable("promo");
        this.Property(p => p.PromotionId).HasColumnName("p_id");
        this.Property(p => p.PromotionConfigId).HasColumnName("pc_id");
        this.Property(p => p.PromotionCode).HasColumnName("p_code");


        this.HasRequired(t => t.PromotionConfig) 
            .WithMany(t => t.Promotions)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.PromotionConfigId }); 
    }
}

public class Promotion
{
    public decimal PromotionId { get; set; }
    public int PromotionConfigId { get; set; }
    public string PromotionCode { get; set; }
}

public PromotionConfigMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(s => s.PromotionConfigId);

    // Properties
    // Table and Column mappings
    this.ToTable("promo_cfg");

    this.Property(p => p.PromotionConfigId).HasColumnName("pc_id");
    this.Property(p => p.AllowOrders).HasColumnName("allow_orders");
    this.HasOptional(p => p.Promotions).WithRequired().Map(x => x.MapKey("pc_id"));
}

public class PromotionConfig
{
    public int PromotionConfigId { get; set; }
    public int AllowOrders { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be, with a big MAY, with a non materialized FK:

```
HasOptional(x => x.SomeProperty).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("intDbColumnName"));
```

========================================================

I remove all unneeded code, the following should do:

```
public class Promotion
{
    public decimal PromotionId { get; set; }
    //Here you do not materialize the FK
    public PromotionConfig PromotionConfig { get; set; }
}

public class PromotionConfig
{
    public decimal PromotionConfigId { get; set; } // you can't do otherwise as
                                                   //you must declare a PK for EF
    public virtual ICollection<Promotion> Promotions { get; set; }
}


public class PromotionMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Promotion>
{
    public PromotionMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(p => p.PromotionId);

        // Properties

        // table and column mappings
        this.ToTable("promo");
        this.Property(p => p.PromotionId).HasColumnName("p_id");

        //if I well understand pc_id is an int that relates to a decimal
        this.HasRequired(p => p.PromotionConfig) 
            .WithMany(pc => pc.Promotions)
            .Map(p => p.MapKey("pc_id")); 

    }
}


public class PromotionConfigMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PromotionConfig> {

    public PromotionConfigMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(s => s.PromotionConfigId);

        // Properties
        // Table and Column mappings
        this.ToTable("promo_cfg");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but this did not work.  I am still getting the following exception base = {"The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Decimal' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid."}

Comment: there should be something else. The types you give are CLR types. But with the given configuration (no materialization of the FK), there should not occur materialization. May you give us a little more of your code, the implied class for example ?

Comment: Forgive me for being slow, but I am not following what you are saying in your answer.  If the HasRequired is correct and all that I need where have I gone wrong in my config?

Comment: As you can see I have created PromotionConfig.PromotionConfigId as an int but in the database it is a numeric(18,0).  If I changed this in my class to be a decimal then ef complains about not being able to map properties of different types.

Comment: Although this didn't exactly solve my problem your persistence got me there in the end.  The PromotionConfigMap needed the type specified. this.Property(p => p.PromotionCofigId).HasColumnName("pc_id").HasColumnType("decimal")